# Powershell Batch Add/Append text to a file name

Tags: powershell

I am trying to batch add text to the titles of several files in a folder. My code works for command line but not PowerShell:

```
for %a in (*.avi, *.mta) do ren "%a" "My Title - %a"
```

Could someone help me adapt this to powershell?

---

Basically I would like to perform the following actions:

Folder Contents:

> 001-episode.avi 002-episode.avi

I would like to add the name of the show to the file

> ShowTitle-001-episode.avi ShowTitle-002-episode.ave

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Found this to work as well.

```
Dir | rename-item -newname  { "My Title -" + $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ChildItem *.avi,*.mta | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "My Title - $($_.Name)" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
get-childitem * | rename-item -newname  { "My Title -" + $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the answers here didn't work for me, they just changed the name to the string part without the $_.Name. For example, if I renamed test.txt with `Dir | rename-item -newname  { "My Title -" + $_.Name }` it would just rename it to

> My Title -

But this worked

```
gci F:path *wildcard -depth 2 | % { rename-item –path $_.Fullname –Newname ( 'My Title -' + $_.basename + $_.extension)}
```